# Recursive search PHP

Tags: php, recursion

How do I recursively search this array of arrays using php.

The array has "ndx", "num", and "'contents" and attached to another array that has the same structure but different values. I can only search the array(recurse =0) the array and the neighbors(recurse =1) or the array and the neighbors of the neighbors (recurse =2) I am searching for the value in the contents.The function's parameters are :
function search($item, $recurse = 0)

bellow is the data in the actual data structure :

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
object(Room)[996]
  private 'ndx' => int 4
  private 'num' => int 19
  private 'contents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'neighbors' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(Room)[995]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(Room)[997]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(Room)[1004]
          ...
1 => 
object(Room)[1003]
  private 'ndx' => int 11
  private 'num' => int 6
  private 'contents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'neighbors' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(Room)[1002]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(Room)[1004]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(Room)[1010]
          ...
2 => 
object(Room)[1005]
  private 'ndx' => int 13
  private 'num' => int 10
  private 'contents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'neighbors' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(Room)[1004]
          ...
      1 => 
        object(Room)[1006]
          ...
      2 => 
        object(Room)[1011]
```